# How to AutoRotate in LineageOS With ADB?

Tags: adb, custom-roms, lineageos, auto-rotation

I am using LOS 14.1 unofficial (by dl12345 user from XDA) in my N910C. AutoRotate doesn't work and i found a solution which is working partly. What does mean partly?

I added these to my build.prob with adb.

```
log.tag.launcher_force_rotate=VERBOSE
lockscreen.rot_override=true
```

And I've set permission of build.prop like this.

```
chmod 644 build.prop
```

Then rebooted to System.

I tested AutoRotate and it is working good even if i am in main (lock) screen. 2-3 days later i realized it is not working anymore mysterious. In the meanwhile i rebooted the device 1-2 times within 2-3 days. I started to look for a new fix and found this command.

```
ro.sf.hwrotation=360
```

I deleted first two (2) commands and added this command to the build.prop with adb and set the permission like that.

Rebooted to System and tested. It is working good and today i realized it is not working again.
I started to think what is the problem? It is working some and not working anymore.

I need your ideas and experiences.

P.S: I don't want to use an app always for this.

**EDIT:** I had edited and pushed build.prop 1 hour ago and had tested, it was working.

I can enable user_rotation to 0, 1, 2 and 3. It is working good but as you know rotating in every app even if in Settings or Phone (Calling). But Auto Rotation is not working.

**EDIT2:** I enabled Auto Rotation with this command, didn't work.

```
root@kali:~/Downloads/platform-tools# adb shell settings put system accelerometer_rotation 1
```

I enabled user_rotation with this command, it is working.

```
root@kali:~/Downloads/platform-tools# adb shell settings put system user_rotation 1
```

Results of rests:

```
Disabled Accelerometer, enabled user_rotation=working
Enabled Acceleremoter, configured user_rotation with 0=not working
Enabled Accelerometer, configured user_rotation with 1=not working
```

As a result when i enabled Auto Rotation, is not working

**EDIT3:** I installed [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wered.sensorsmultitool) app and tested Accelerometer. I can rotate my phone 360 degree without enabling AutoRotate feature. I had thought my phone's accelerometer is broken, but not.

Answer (score 1):

[Android 4.2](https://gist.github.com/alekswn/053003233c4033aa4d92)

Auto rotate on:

`adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:accelerometer_rotation --bind value:i:1`

Auto rotate off:

`adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:accelerometer_rotation --bind value:i:0`

Landscape:

`adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:1`

Portrait:

`adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:0`

[Android 8](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/rotate-suggestions)

Auto rotate on:

`adb shell settings put secure show_rotation_suggestions 1`

Auto rotate off:

`adb shell settings put secure show_rotation_suggestions 0`

introduction mode can be reset by altering the associated Settings.Secure value. This accomplished easiest by running the following command from a privileged adb instance:

`adb shell settings put secure num_rotation_suggestions_accepted 0`

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I have Nougat 7.1.2 and as i mentioned i can rotate my phohe but just 5-10 minutes. I am rebooting my phohe with enabled AutoRotate feature. I can rotate my phone 360 degree. But when i try again after 30 minutes, it is gone. I can't. I guess something is overriding this but what overriding i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Im also running an unofficial LOS 14.1--7.1.2 (orig. 6.0), and I've learned that, while being debuggable &selinux-permissive, ANY little system change requires that /system/ be remounted -o rw.  Once I ran the cmd via terminal prior to changes, I experienced NO more issues with substratum, exposed, etc. My Superuser's perms are 777, so I had assumed that also having a permissive kernel would grant god-like powers, but certain pid's & such keep me humble. 
Also maybe important (certainly is for my LG), build.prop changes persist only when done properly via my TWRP terminal, as that shows my default build.prop always, lurking to overwrite /revert my naive tweaks. Good lookin' out, TWRP.